# importing mysql .sql file appears to randomly selects which tables to import or not

Tags: mysql

I have database A. I issue this command against it:

```
mysqldump --host=localhost  -uroot -p"mypassword"  my_db_name > file.sql
```

now I take this file to machine B, running mysql too. I create a database:

```
create database newdb;
```

I then:

```
mysql --host=localhost  -uroot -proot newdb < file.sql
```

My problem is that not all tables that exist in file.sql are created in the new database! I clearly see `CREATE TABLES users` in the content of the file.sql followed by thousands of `INSERT` calls for content in that table.

But `users` table is never created in the new database. I am completely lost as to why.

Comment: This may be caused by an encoding mismatch. Your `create database newdb` does not specify any default encoding. It may happen that `users` table has some foreign key on another table, and the referencing and referenced column encodings do not match.

Comment: What do your error logs say `[/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log]`? What about general query log `[/var/log/mysql/mysql.log]`? Any chance you are running two very different versions of mysql servers?

Comment: The answers to the question can be guesses only as there is no SQL data provided. Actually the Q does not contain [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the readers can not reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete whole `newdb` database;
2. Restart `mysqld`;
3. Run `mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases -u root -p root` on machine B;
4. Create `newdb` again (or maybe call it `newdb2` just to be sure);
5. Delete `file.sql` on machine B, copy `file.sql` again from machine A and import by `mysql --host=localhost  -uroot -proot newdb < file.sql`;
6. Run `SHOW engine innodb STATUS;` and or `show table status` and analyze results.

Answer (score 1):

If you have foreign keys, the tables might be created in the wrong order and since the constraints can't be created, creating the table fails. Try adding `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` in the beginning of the dump and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Copy a `CREATE TABLE` that failed to work.  In the commandline tool "mysql", paste that.  What messages, if any do you get?  Does it create the table?

Please provide that `CREATE` for us; there may be some odd clues.

Also provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%enforce%';`

Comment: | enforce_gtid_consistency | OFF   |

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%engine%';`  And what about my other requests?

Comment: +----------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                    | Value  |
+----------------------------------+--------+
| default_storage_engine           | InnoDB |
| default_tmp_storage_engine       | InnoDB |
| disabled_storage_engines         |        |
| internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine | InnoDB |
+----------------------------------+--------+